# Naming A Number of Variables in Matlab

Tags: matlab

If I need to get some variables values from a vector in Matlab, I could do, for instance,

```
x = A(1); y = A(2); z = A(3);
```

or I think I remember I could do something like

> [x, y, z] = A;

However Matlab is not recognizing this format. what was the correct syntax? Thanks!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

@Thales is correct. If `A` happens to be a [cell array](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_prog/what-is-a-cell-array.html) rather than a matrix you could do something like this:

```
A = {1 2 3};
[x,y,z] = A{:}
```

But that is as close as it gets unless `A` is a function.

Comment: That is interesting and gives us an idea. I will edit my answer to add what you wrote.

Answer (score 1):

The right way to do it is:

```
x = A(1); y = A(2); z = A(3);
```

This `[x, y, z] = A` makes no sense because A is not a function. You can use more variables in the left-hand side of an assignment as the outputs of a function. If `A` is a variable, then you just can't do it.

Edit:
@horchler suggestion was to use a cell array to do it.
Perhaps then you can write:

```
A = 1:3;
A = num2cell(A);
[x,y,z]=A{:}
```

And that will work. First you [convert your array to a cell](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/num2cell.html), then use the assignment to define the x, y and z variables.
It is worth mentioning that this will do the trick for you, but that is not efficient. A cell array in MATLAB is much slower than an array itself and assign different elements of the array to different variables instead of using cell arrays will run faster though.